# Retrieve Dictionnary value and append them into an array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have this `Dictionnary`:

```
["1hoxy7StFyU4QzQTwgDrwAoCZ": {
    address = "example2";
    date = "28-02-2017";
    location = "....";
    number = 1111;
    user = S4KaKn5Qz4bDDha57DMLcnaCHn21;
}"1hoxy7StFyU4QzQfrsqfsqfDZz": {
    address = "example2";
    date = "28-02-2017";
    location = "....";
    number = 222;
    user = S4KaKn5Qz4bDDha57DMLcnaCHn22;
}]
```

I want to retrieve all the `user` values of this `Dictionnary` and append them into an `Array`.
This `Dictionnary` is retrieved with Firebase database.

```
  if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

                print(dict)

                self.asksList.append(dict["user"] as! String)

                print(self.asksList)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: That looks like it might be an array of dictionaries... ?

Comment: There is no price key in your dictionary.

Comment: Use the `map` function for that

Comment: The `user` key sorry... I correct this.

Comment: what is `map` function Sylvan D Ash? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having nested dictionary so you can get all the `user` this way.

```
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : [String:Any]] {
    for (_, value) in dict { 
        if let user = value["user"] as? String {
            self.asksList.append(user)
        }
    }       
    //Firebase completion block will called in main thread so directly reload the tableView
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**OR** you can use `flatMap` instead of iterating through the for loop

```
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : [String:Any]] {
    let array = dict.flatMap { $1["user"] as? String }
    self.asksList += array 
    //Firebase completion block will called in main thread so directly reload the tableView
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV Welcome mate :)